# QtSQL double inserting into db

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt

Problem is that when I exec sql insert query (I'm using Qt Creator and sqlite), two new rows are added into database instead of one.

Here's code block

```
void MainWindow::on_insertButton_clicked(){
 db.open();
 QString name = ui->nameLineEdit->text();
 QString queryString = "INSERT INTO highscores (name, score) VALUES '%1',%2";
 QSqlQuery query(queryString.arg(name).arg(score));
 query.exec();
}
```

This code should insert values name and score into database just once but after query exec two same rows are inserted.

Anyone has an idea what's the problem?

Comment: Clearly, the problem is that you are calling the code twice (the second possibility that you have an insert trigger that inserts two rows is probably very, very remote).  I would suggest that you put debugging statements into the C++ code or use a debugger to track what is happening.

Comment: Are you saying that if you click on the button twice, two rows are inserted, and you don't want that?

Comment: I just want to insert data in db when I click QPushButton. I am not clicking it twice, it's just one click and two rows are inserted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isntead of

```c
QString queryString = "INSERT INTO highscores (name, score) VALUES '%1',%2";
```

you should write

```c
QString queryString = "INSERT INTO highscores (name, score) VALUES ('%1',%2)";
```

SQL's `INSERT` command expects **a list of datasets** after `VALUES` separated by commas, each of them *in parentheses* with their column values.

The following command inserts one tuple into the table `table`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2);
```

```
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| val1 | val2 |
```

Because you didn't put the two values in parentheses you asked SQLite to insert *two datasets* with *one value* each:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES val1, val2;
```

```
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| val1 |      |
| val2 |      |
```

*(The funny thing is that I tested this with both my SQLite and MySQL installations. They both threw an error when I omitted the parentheses at all. But this may depend on the version and some options you are using.)*

### Please **never** use `QString::arg` to fill in arguments of a SQL query!

(Or any other method of string building, like concatenation.) **This can lead to a possible [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).**

In order to build statements with variable arguments you should use *SQL prepared statements* as provided by [QSqlQuery bound values](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values):

```c
QString queryString = "INSERT INTO highscores (name, score) VALUES (?,?)";
QSqlQuery query(queryString);
query.addBindValue(name);
query.addBindValue(score);
query.exec();
```

Note that I did not quote the string argument in the prepared statement.

Comment: I added qDebug("foo") after query.exec() and two new rows are added in db instead of one

Comment: @B.P. And only one line saying "foo" appears on the debug output?

Comment: Try putting the `?,?` in parentheses as shown in the updated answer. AFAIK after `VALUES` comes a list of datasets to be inserted, so you provided two datasets. A dataset consisting of multiple values is noted as a tuple in parentheses. But I thought that it should have lead to an error when omitting the parentheses at all. If this is true, I highlight this in the answer for future readers.

Comment: I replaced my query block with block you wrote, and after that my program started to work correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your button click event is called twice. This is usually because `connectSlotsByName(this);` being used twice. Delete this line in your code and it should work.

Comment: There's single line that says: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow), and when i delete it  buttons won't  work.